# Wordpress custom form post to different page

Tags: urls, forms

I have a site which is developed with `PHP` and recently I added `Wordpress` blog(same domain with `/blog` url) to that.

I would like to implement two extra functions(subscribe/contactus) on that blog which is already existing & handling on `PHP` site.

I found few plugins like `Visual Form Builder` to build custom forms and also widgets.

I need to use existing php back-end functions to handle contact-us and subscription functionality in the blog as well. My question is how to change the action url on those custom build forms(in the blog) to post details directly to that existing functions in the `PHP` site.

Note : i'm very new to wordpress.

Comment: Do you want to _migrate_ the form to WordPress side completely? If you are keeping non–WP part of site it could be convenient to just leave it working (if it's not broken...), at least endpoint it points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to use `contact form 7` plugin then you can find very detailed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177844/how-to-change-form-action-url-for-contact-form-7).
Basically you need to create a custom filter using `wpcf7_form_action_url` hook.

Another option would be to create child-theme and create your custom form there, but that IMHO would be a bit of an overkill.